# Unicode character does not align to line in TextView

Tags: android, unicode, textview

The exact string I use for the TextView is:

`val myText = "\u2022\u2022\u2022\u2022\u2022\u2022\u2022\u2022\u2022\u202244"`

`myTextView.text = myText`

The font I use in TextView is **Inter Regular**. This does not happen with the system font.

The screenshot is like this:

[image]

Why wasn't it aligned properly?

Comment: Possibly a bug on layout engine (or in the font). Try to change the font, but I would file a bug report anyway.

Comment: Yes, I think it's a font error too. Thank you!